# nginx php-cgi secure few domains

Tags: php, nginx

Hello I would like to know if I have many domains on one server how to secure the domains so if one will be hacked the attacker won't have access to others. What is the best practise with that chroot or what? I'm using debian stable + nginx + php-fastcgi.

Comment: If the attacker has access to the system user root, there is no way to protect something.

Comment: Well let's say that somebody exploited site1 thought some kind of PHP bug and he injected shell script and there is also site2,site3 on my webserver I want to protect site2,site3 from being hacked as well , I'm sure there is a way to do that I'm not sure which one should I pick.